# Model not loading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I can't get a hold why I cannot load this own written model into my controller. The Model code:

```
class Storage extends CI_Model
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

function getStorageByID( $storageID, $accountID = -1 )
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('storage')->where('storageID', $storageID);
    if ($accountID != -1)
        $query->where('storageAccountID', $accountID);
    return $this->finishQuery( $query );
}

function getStorageByAccount( $accountID )
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('storage')->where('storageAccountID', $accountID)->limit( $limit );
    return $this->finishQuery( $query );
}

function finishQuery( $query )
{
    $row = $query->get()->result();  
    return objectToArray($row);
}
}
```

The code in the controller used to load and execute:

```
$this->load->model('storage'); // Line 147
$storageDetails = $storage->getStorageByAccount( $userData['accountID'] ); // Line 148
```

The error:

```
Message: Undefined variable: storage
Filename: controllers/dashboard.php
Line Number: 148
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStorageByAccount() on a non-object in /home/dev/concept/application/controllers/dashboard.php on line 148
```

I've tried var_dump'ing the model load command, yet that only returns NULL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
$this->load->model('storage');
$storageDetails = $this->storage->getStorageByAccount( $userData['accountID'] );
```

Comment: Oh gosh, you're completely right! How did I look over this?! Thanks for your input, I'm going for a coffee break first.

Comment: No problem.. Glad it helped. It's easy to miss the smallest things :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the model you are calling and the name of the model as you wish to call it from your controller. In this fashion, you can do the following.

```
 $this->load->model('storage', 'storage');
 $storageDetails = $storage->getStorageByAccount( $userData['accountID'] ); // Line 148

 // but if you wanted you could use your alias to write as followed
 $this->load->model('storage', 'my_storage');
 $storageDetails = $my_storage->getStorageByAccount( $userData['accountID'] ); // Line 148
```

In order to make your model loading work you must reference what you are loading and then what you are calling what you have loaded within the context of the file you are loading it into. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I've tried this already, i've done the following:

    `$this->load->model('storage', 'idiotmodel');
    $storageDetails = $idiotmodel->getStorageByAccount( $userData['accountID']);`

Sadly this doesn't work either, I get the same error with just another variable name. You can load models without specifing their target name, I use it in other places in the controller with different models and that works fine.

Comment: @PatrickRombouts have you tried `$this->load->model('models/storage', 'storage');`

Comment: Just tried it, getting the following error: `Unable to locate the model you have specified: storage`, removing the models/ part brings us back to the original error.

Comment: That's a negative too. Also tried the old way of loading them with the function Model with a parent::Model(), didn't give any result either.